# Adding clickListener to map markersList and send data to next activity?

Tags: java, android, google-maps, google-api, google-maps-markers

I am working in an app where i need to add more than 1 pins at a time related to their categories, same sub categories will have same markers, every thing i have done is working perfectly now i want to send category when i click on marker. I have also added the listener each time, but it is only working well for the first index,
can you please check my code and let me know what is the issue
This is the method to show pins and i have added the click listener here

```
 private void showMarkersOnMap(SubcategoriesDataModel dataModel) {

        allLocationsList = dataModel.getLocationsList();
        if (markerList != null){
            try {
                markerList.clear();
            }catch (Exception e){
                Log.d("MapFragment", "RemoveMarker"+ e.toString());
            }

        }
        for (int i = 0; i < allLocationsList.size(); i++) {

            String str = allLocationsList.get(i).getLat_long();
            List<String> latLong = Arrays.asList(str.split(","));
            latLong.size();
            int categoryId = allLocationsList.get(i).getId();
            LatLng latLng = new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(latLong.get(0)), 
            Double.parseDouble(latLong.get(1)));
            String markerTitle = allLocationsList.get(i).getName();
            String snippet = allLocationsList.get(i).getAddress();
            CameraPosition cameraPosition = new 
            CameraPosition.Builder().target(latLng).zoom(12).build();
            if (mMap != null) {
                switch (dataModel.getName()) {
                    case "Category1": {
                        myMarker =  createMarker(latLng.latitude, latLng.longitude, markerTitle, snippet, R.drawable.category1);
                        mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));
                        subcategoriesIds.add(categoryId);
                        markerList.add(myMarker);
                        break;
                    }
                    case "Category2": {
                        myMarker =  createMarker(latLng.latitude, latLng.longitude, markerTitle, snippet, R.drawable.category2);
                        mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));
                        subcategoriesIds.add(categoryId);
                        markerList.add(myMarker);
                        break;
                    }
                    case "Category3": {
                        myMarker = createMarker(latLng.latitude, latLng.longitude, markerTitle, snippet, R.drawable.category3);
                        mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));
                        subcategoriesIds.add(categoryId);
                        markerList.add(myMarker);
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }

        }


        for (int m = 0; m < subcategoriesIds.size(); m++){
            int finalM = m;
            mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(marker -> {
                Intent mainIntent = new Intent(context , SubCategoriesDetailsActivity.class);
                Utilities.saveInt(context, "subCategoryId", subcategoriesIds.get(finalM));
                startActivity(mainIntent);
                return true;
            });
        }

    }
```

Here is the code for adding marker

```
  protected Marker createMarker(double latitude, double longitude, String title, String snippet, int iconResID) {
        return mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .position(new LatLng(latitude, longitude))
                .anchor(0.5f, 0.5f)
                .title(title)
                .snippet(snippet)
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(iconResID)));
    }
```

Comment: The map has only one `OnMarkerClickListener` so  your loop on `subcategoriesIds` keeps overwriting the marker listener leaving the last one.  You'll have to rework you marker listener code to use the `marker` parameter to then populate your intent as needed.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [`Marker.setTag()`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/Marker#setTag(java.lang.Object)) for store "`subcategoriesIds`" in corresponding `Marker` object and [`Marker.getTag()`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/Marker#getTag()) to retrieve it in `OnMarkerClickListener()`. Something like that:

```
...
// wrapper class for marker custom properties
public class MarkerCategory {
    private int categoryName;
    private int categoryId;
   
    public MarkerCategory(String categoryName, int categoryId) {
        this.categoryName = categoryName;
        this.categoryId = categoryId;
    }

    public int getCategoryId() {
        return categoryId;
    }
      
    public String getCategoryName() {
        return categoryName;
    }
}
...
```

In this case, in `createMarker()`, you should create an object with `"subcategory"` properties (e.g. name and id) and assign it to the marker you are creating:

```
protected Marker createMarker(double latitude, double longitude, String title, String snippet, int iconResID, String categoryName, int categoryId) {
        Marker markerWithTag = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .position(new LatLng(latitude, longitude))
                .anchor(0.5f, 0.5f)
                .title(title)
                .snippet(snippet)
                 .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(iconResID)));
         
         markerWithTag.setTag(new MarkerCategory(categoryName, categoryId));

         return markerWithTag;
}
```

Then, in `OnMarkerClickListener()` you can get stored object with `"subcategory"` properties and apply it to activity call:

```
// no need to 'for' loop to setOnMarkerClickListener
// for (int m = 0; m < subcategoriesIds.size(); m++){
//      int finalM = m;
        mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(marker -> {
          
            // get object with subcategory properties
            MarkerCategory markerCategory = (MarkerCategory) marker.getTag();

            Intent mainIntent = new Intent(context , SubCategoriesDetailsActivity.class);
            Utilities.saveInt(context, "subCategoryId", markerCategory.getId());
            startActivity(mainIntent);
            return true;
        });
//    }
```